# Unable to log 'SparkXGBRegressorModel' to Feature Store on Databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, mlflow, mlops

I am working on an MLOps project on Azure Databricks and after training the model using the 'SparkXGBRegressorModel' library I want to log it to Feature Store. The problem is that using the fs.log_model() function it raises an error because of the model data type which is 'SparkXGBRegressorModel'.

Does anyone know how can I log this model to Feature Store?

I tried to register it to Feature Store using this code I found on the Databricks [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/machine-learning/feature-store/train-models-with-feature-store):

```
fs.log_model(
            model=xgb_model,
            artifact_path=f"{model_name}_artifact_path",
            flavor=mlflow.xgboost,
            training_set = training_set ,
            registered_model_name = model_name
        )
```

But as I said it raised the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'SparkXGBRegressorModel' object has no attribute 'save_model'
```

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `flavor=mlflow.spark` worked for me

Comment: Thanks for editing! An explanation as to why this code solves the problem would improve it even more. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers, such as yourself, of this post.